# $Sp(V)$ acts transitively on $V^*-\{0\}$ where $\Omega$ here is symplectic 2 form

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $\dim(V)=6$. Show that $Sp(V,\Omega)$ acts transitively on $V^*-\{0\}$, where $\Omega$ here is a symplectic 2 form on $V$. ($V^*$ here is algebraic dual of $V$)

Comment: Does $V^*$ denote the algebraic dual? What is the action? People unfamiliar with the question will have a hard time guessing.

Comment: This $\Omega$ is not present in the body of the text.

Comment: @rschwieb: all of the stuff mentioned in the question is standard and natural. Still, since $\Omega$ is non-degenerate, we can translate all questions about forms to equivalent questions about vectors by $v \mapsto \Omega(v, \cdot)$ and its inverse, so it's a bit puzzling that the author insists on working with $V^*$.

Comment: i edited it again

Comment: @Berci: $\Omega$ is implicit in the definition of $\operatorname{Sp}(V) = \operatorname{Sp}(V,\Omega)$ (the linear maps preserving the symplectic form).

Comment: @Marek Even if it is standard and natural to you, people unfamiliar with the question will have a hard time guessing. It's best policy to recommend this to increase the number of potential answerers.

Comment: Differential geometry tag is used. Are we allowed to infer that the OP is only interested in the real case? When e.g. $\Omega$ is in the standard form?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Show first that any non-zero vector is part of a symplectic basis.